# jQuery refer to control ID in template field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to refer to the ID of a control in my javascript. The control is in template field.

Here is what I've done:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#ReqDate2.ClientID').dynDateTime({
                       showsTime: true,
                       ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
                       daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
                       align: "BR",
                       dlectric: false,
                       singleClick: false,
                       displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                       button: ".next()"
                  });
            });
 </script>                    
<asp:TextBox ID="ReqDate2" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Style="width: 128px"></asp:TextBox>
     <img src="../Images/calender.png" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

This code is supposed to make the calender javascript pop up when I click on the calender image but it does not happen.

I think it's because I am not selecting the ID of the textbox correctly: $('#ReqDate2.ClientID')

How should I select it instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of accessing `textbox id` use its `class name`

Try this:Its working fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Calender").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"
    });
});
```

You should change the itemtemplate as well .

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass = "Calender" />
   <img src="calender.png" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `CssClass="Calender"` instead of `class="Calender"`. This is asp.net control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#ReqDate2').dynDateTime({
    showsTime: true,
    ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
    daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
    align: "BR",
    electric: false,
    singleClick: false,
    displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
    button: ".next()"
});
```

when you are having a unique id there is no need to add any other selector with that.

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.net renders the changes the ID so if you view the HTML of the output it most likely will not be `ReqDate2`

To make the JavaScript reference the correct ID, use

```
 $('#<%= ReqDate2.ClientID %>').dynDateTime({
```

As this is a `itemTemplate` I would advise against using that approach and to use a class approach by lakshmi prakasan

Answer (score 0):

Using classes worked great, however since I have validation as well, now its not working. I take out the validation and it works fine. Below validation is commented.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Drop Off - Date &amp; Time"> 
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dropoffdateandtime" runat="server" class = "Calender"
                            Text="<%# Bind('dropoffdateandtime') %>" />
                         **<%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropoffdateandtime" ErrorMessage="date &amp; time is required" ForeColor="#999999"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>**
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                     <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                     <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".Calender").dynDateTime({
          showsTime: true,
          ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
          daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
          align: "BR",
          electric: false,
          singleClick: false,
          displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
          button: ".next()"
      });
  });
</script>
```